# Opening different iframe depending on different button click

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe

i am trying to open different iframe windows by assigning iframe src to a variable ,
when the page initially loads it should show only two buttons on the page , when i click on the button , an iframe should get loaded depending on which button is pressed , i tried doing something like this to create buttons and creating iframes , but it is not working

```
<button id="b1">Button 1</button>
<button id="b2">Button 2</button>
<iframe scrolling="no" src="whatnext">
</iframe>
<script>
var b1 = document.getElementById('b1'), b2 = document.getElementById('b2');
var x = "Hello!";
function showX() {
    var whatnext;
    if b1.onclick==true
        whatnext= "http://community.sitepoint.com/" style="border: 0px none; height: 1555px; margin-left: -116px; margin-top: -25px; width: 930px;"
        elseif b2.onclick=true
        whatnext= "http://community.sitepoint.com/" style="border: 0px none; height: 555px; margin-left: -116px; margin-top: -25px; width: 330px;"
}
</script>
and another piece of trial is
<button id="b1">Button 1</button>
<button id="b2">Button 2</button>
<iframe scrolling="no" src="x" style="border: 0px none; height: 1555px; margin-left: -116px; margin-top: -25px; width: 930px;">
</iframe>
<script>
var b1 = document.getElementById('b1'), b2 = document.getElementById('b2');
var x ;
function showX() {
    src="https:http://stackoverflow.com";
}
b1.onclick = function() {
    x = "http://stackoverflow.com;
    showX();
};
b2.onclick = function() {
    x = "www.sitepoint.com";
    showX();
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to change the src attribute of the iframe on click. I added the src to the buttons usind the data attribute.
Here is the example http://jsfiddle.net/8wLm42ns/2/
The HTML

```
    <button class="loadiframe" id="b1" data-src="http://jquery.com/" data-width="500" data-height="400">Button 1</button>
<button class="loadiframe" id="b2" data-src="http://sitepoint.com" data-width="650" data-height="350">Button 2</button>

<iframe id='frame' frameborder="0" scrolling="no" width="500" height="400">
```

jQuery

```
$('.loadiframe').on('click', function(){
    var src = $(this).data('src'),
        width = $(this).data('width'),
        height = $(this).data('height');
    $('#frame').css({
        width: width,
        height: height
    }).attr('src', src);
});
```

For javascript solution try this http://jsfiddle.net/8wLm42ns/3/

The HTML

```
<div class="loadiframe">
    <button id="b1" data-src="http://jquery.com/" data-width="500" data-height="400">Button 1</button>
    <button id="b2" data-src="http://sitepoint.com" data-width="650" data-height="350">Button 2</button>
</div>
<iframe id='frame' frameborder="0" scrolling="no" width="500" height="400">
```

javaScript - add in head section

```
function iframeChange() {
    var buttons = document.querySelector(".loadiframe"),
        iframe = document.getElementById('frame');

    buttons.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
        iframe.src = e.target.dataset.src;
        iframe.width = e.target.dataset.width;
        iframe.height = e.target.dataset.height;
    });
}
window.onload = iframeChange;
```

Comment: thanks for the great help bro........i was struggling with this alot from quite long

Comment: hello bojan , the solution is great but still one thing this script is not providing is that making different iframe structure for different button click , each button is loading a different iframe , but the size of iframe too must be different for both the button , for eg. for the first button click the ifram should load with width = 500 and height = 400 , but for the next button click it should be widht = 650 and height = 350

Comment: Are you using the jQuery solution or javascript?

Comment: i can use any one i dont have any constraints on whether to use jquery or javascript , but i think understanding javascript will be more easier for me ,if possible you can extend the solution using both the methods which will be more helpful for me and the community too

Comment: @user1597336 I have updated my answer to include different width and height :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this solution, at click on a button you load the webpage on a specific iframe, no jquery required.

JSBIN here
http://jsbin.com/gebelatomiya/1/

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
function loadFrame (elm){
    var frame1 = document.getElementById('frame1');
    frame1.src = elm.dataset.src;
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <button id="b1" data-src="http://www.w3schools.com" onClick="loadFrame(this)">Button 1</button>
    <button id="b2" data-src="http://www.sony.com" onClick="loadFrame(this)">Button 2</button>
    <iframe id="frame1" scrolling="no"></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: very thanks gibbok both the codes are working and i am going to try both and see the page loading , whichever will load faster i will be using it , but thanks for letting the community know the new way to do the same thing