# HTML button targeting

Tags: javascript, html, button, iframe, target

I have two buttons on a page and two different frames. When clicked on button 1, I want it to show on frame a and when clicked on button 2, I want it to show on frame b. For some reason I can't get the buttons to show on different frames. Only one frame.

Did some testing, it seems like the only target matters is in the first form action tag. The targets in the button tags are useless.

```
<body>
<center>
<form action="test.php" method="post" target="frame_a">
<button type="submit" name="action" value="Active" 
target="frame_a">Active</button>
<button type="submit" name="action1" value="Completed" 
formaction="test2.php" target="frame_b">Completed</button>
</td>
</form>

<iframe width="900" height="1000" src="" name="frame_a" width="100%" 
height="100%"></iframe>

<iframe width="900" height="1000" src="" name="frame_b" width="100%" 
height="100%"></iframe>

</body>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26253115/4229270

Answer (score 0):

Try putting the buttons in a separate form

```
<form action="test.php" method="post" target="frame_a">
    <button type="submit" name="action" value="Active" 
target="frame_a">Active</button>
</form>

<form action="test.php" method="post" target="frame_b">
    <button type="submit" name="action1" value="Completed" formaction="test2.php" target="frame_b">Completed</button>
</form>
```